# OpenGL slows for 5k points

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing a [SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) library and want to visualize its work with OpenGL. I need to draw some 100k points and a few hundred rectangles and I would expect that OpenGL can handle it easily. However, after the number of points reaches 5k my program slows down.

I am new to OpenGL, so I guess I am not doing things in a proper way. I used [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) for learning.

As the program works, it spits out certain events from which only a few are relevant:

- Point Created (size_t id, float x,y,z;)
- Point Updated (szie_t id, float x,y,z;)
- Position Estimated (Quaternion Q, Vector3D T)

The part of the program that visualizes these events (simplified) works as follows.

We assign a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to each point. In order not to allocate a new buffer every time we get a new point, I decided to keep a repository of buffers. As a new point arrives we assign to it a "free" buffer from the repository. Only if the repo is empty, we allocate a new buffer with `glGenBuffers`.

```
std::stack<GLuint> point_buffer_stack;
std::map<size_t, GLuint> active_points;

void OnPointCreated(size_t id,  float x, float y, float z ){
  GLuint point_buffer_id;
  if(point_buffer_stack.empty()){
    glGenBuffers(1, &point_buffer_id);
  }
  else {
    point_buffer_id = point_buffer_stack.top();
    point_buffer_stack.pop(); 
  }
  active_points[id] = point_buffer_id;

  OnPointUpdated(id, x, y, z);
     
}

void OnPointUpdated(size_t id, float x, float y, float z){
  GLuint point_buffer_id = active_points[id];
  float buffer[3] = {x,y,z};
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, point_buffer_id);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(buffer), buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
}

void OnPointDeleted(size_t id){
  GLuint point_buffer_id = active_points[id];
  point_buffer_stack.push(point_buffer_id);
  active_points.erase(id);
}
```

Draw the frame only when the position is updated:

```
void OnPositionUpdated (const glm::mat4 & projection){
  glm::mat4 model_view_projection;
  /* Compute  model_view_projection and set the corresponding UniformMatrix4fv for using in the  vertex shader */

  // Draw points 
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  for(const auto & id_vertex: active_points){
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id_vertex.second);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
      0,                  // layout from vertex shader.
      3,                  // 3D
      GL_FLOAT,           // type
      GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
      0,                  // stride
      (void *) 0            // array buffer offset
      );
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
  }
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

  /*Draw a rectangle that shows the current position by drawing two triangles */

  glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  glfwPollEvents();
}
```

On my Asus Zenbook with Intel® Xe Graphics, Ubuntu 20.04, OpenGL starts to lag behind the camera at ~5k points. After some time I get an insufficient memory error from OpenCV (which is built with OpenGL support).

Is this expected? What am I doing wrong? How to solve this issue?

For the reference, the initialization of OpenGL is done as follows:

```
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "SLAM 3D visualization", NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> We assign a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to each point.

That's your problem. This means you are allocating an entire buffer object for all of 12 bytes of memory. Putting each point in its own buffer *also* means that you must render each point with a separate draw call.

None of that is a recipe for performance.

Create a single large buffer for all the points you intend to use, and render them all with a single draw call. If you need to change parameters or something between points, make them a separate vertex attribute. Or failing that, make them uniforms to your shader and render all of the points that use one set of parameters, change the uniforms, then render the next points that use the new parameters, etc.